# How to capture response code in call forwarding using **21*mobile_number#?

Tags: android, call, forwarding

I am trying to capture the response code while activating the call forwarding using MMI Code via android application as on the phone it just shows activates or deactivates. Anyone if knows the format of the response code or any method other than phonestatelistner kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This service is not supported by google. checkout this issue has been raised https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285

Comment: IExtendedNetworkService could have been used to intercept USSD responses but its also suspended by google https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57120